# How to embed a code editor in a static github page

Tags: html, editor, github-pages, ace-editor

I want to embed a code editor in GitHub pages, which is a static environment, so the application must not use Node.js

I have already tried ace.js, and done some Google searches but have been unable to find any workarounds for this issue, Any help would be appreciated. 
EDIT: Ace.js requires Node.js to run, which is unavailable to a static page. Embedding via the recommended method on their pages fails to work with the error`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.` This is due to the lack of Node.js, which is not available in this environment

Comment: "I have already tried ace.js" — How? What were the results of your attempt? Please read [ask]; provide a [mcve]; ask a *specific* question. (I'm guessing that the *editing* isn't the problem but that you are struggling with *saving* the result, but your question lacks enough detail to be sure).

Comment: Updated to be more descriptive. The problem is not saving, it is actually getting an editor to run in the browser.

Comment: Ace.js does not require Node.js to run. I followed their instructions and it worked without a problem. I didn't involve Node.js at all. Using the file they recommend in their example I can see where it defines `require`. You are either following some different instructions or did not follow them accurately. There isn't enough in your question to tell what you are doing.

Comment: Have you tried putting it on a github.io site? This is stated in the first line.

Comment: I was running it from a local file, which is the *worst possible place* to try to run it (since the browser imposes the most limits there). If it works there then it will work anywhere. (Well, CSPs or `sandbox` excepted, but you don't get those on github.io and if you did then you'd get a completely different error message).

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about providing a [mcve] and clearly describing what you are doing (see my earlier comment about not know what instructions you are following).

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong repository for ace.js, I was using ajaxorg/ace when I should have been using ajaxorg/ace-builds.